# How to list the pcolors of neighboring clusters?

Tags: netlogo

I have different clusters of patches, each colored differently and with one turtle that functions as the government.
I need to let the government know what are the pcolors of the neighboring clusters.

I tried to make a list of with the colors' ID of the neighbors, but so far I have only been able to make a list of lists of all patches neighbor

The relevant code that I used is:

```
governments-own[
list-neighbors
govcolorid
]

to setup
ask governments [
...
set govcolorid pcolor
...]
end

to find-neighbors
foreach sort governments [
ask ? [
let my-patch patches with [ pcolor = [ govcolorid ] of myself ]
set list-neighbors (list [[pcolor] of neighbors] of my-patch)
]]
```

This code prints a list-neighbors that looks like this:

```
[[[18 92 85 18 92 85 18 18] [85 11 85 85 85 18 85 85] [85 85 85 85 85 18 85 85]]]
```

But what I need is only the neighboring clusters pcolor minus the govcolorid  (in this case 85):

```
[18 92 11]
```

I tried to use map, sentence and remove-duplicates, but so far I was unable to reach any result. If you have in mind useful tips or examples, please share them.

EDIT:

Following your comments I solved the issue with this following colde:

```
to find-neighbors-patch
  foreach sort governments [
    ask ? [
  let _c [idgov] of ?
  let _frnds patches with [pcolor = _c]
  let _nmes (patch-set [neighbors] of _frnds) with [pcolor != _c]
  set list-neighbors-clusters remove-duplicates [pcolor] of _nmes
    ]]
end
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you nest your list-neighbors inside of another list? It seems redundant.

Comment: Also, why do you sort the governments? I don't see why you need to maintain order. You may want to just try ask governments [ let my-patch patches ...  set list-neighbors ...]

Comment: Is your my-patch variable trying to just get the agent's patch? if so, why not just say patch-here. My-patch is actually an agent set which is a little confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a reporter procedure:

```
to-report find-nbr-colors [#gvt]
  let _c [color] of #gvt
  let _frnds patches with [pcolor = _c]
  let _nmes (patch-set [neighbors] of _frnds) with [pcolor != _c]
  report remove-duplicates [pcolor] of _nmes
end
```

Comment: I have a follow-up question. I am now trying to link each government with the governments of the neighboring clusters. Which procedure would you suggest me to use? I tried with member? and turtles-on, but I must be making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Ok, I resolved my follow up question. All I had to to was to convert the list into an agentset. Again, thank you for the previous help.

Answer (score 2):

To take what your output is to what your desired output is, try the following code:
Essentially, reduce the list of lists to a single list, remove duplicates, and then get rid the value you want.

```
set list-neighbors filter [ ? != 85] remove-duplicates reduce [sentence ?1 ?2] (first list-neighbors)
```